# Firebase DatabaseReference null pointer exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onclicklistener

I have just created a Hello World app with four EditText and a button. The app is crashing with the following error:
I'm getting null pointer exception on the button click event.

StudentInformation class:

```
class StudentInformation {
private String name, rollNo, courseName, marks;
StudentInformation(String nameTxt, String rollNoTxt, String courseNameTxt, String marksTxt){
    this.name = nameTxt;
    this.rollNo = rollNoTxt;
    this.courseName = courseNameTxt;
    this.marks = marksTxt;
}

StudentInformation(){
    this.name = "";
    this.rollNo = "";
    this.courseName = "";
    this.marks = "";

}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRollNo() {
    return rollNo;
}

public void setRollNo(String rollNo) {
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public String getMarks() {
    return marks;
}

public void setMarks(String marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
}
```

}

My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    StudentInformation studentInformation;
    EditText name, rollNo, course, marks;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button saveToDatabase = findViewById(R.id.button);

    name = findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    rollNo = findViewById(R.id.rollNoText);
    course = findViewById(R.id.courseNameText);
    marks = findViewById(R.id.marksText);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("user");

    saveToDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            studentInformation = new StudentInformation(name.getText().toString(), rollNo.getText().toString(), course.getText().toString(), marks.getText().toString());
            mDatabaseReference.setValue(studentInformation);


     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
//                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Edit: As pointed out, I have used the wrong id. It is corrected after usign R.id.button instead of R.id.bottom but now I'm getting another null reference on line:

```
mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("user");
```

As my previous issue and this one is also related to Null Pointer Exception, that's why I did not created a new question for that.

Can anyone please help with it. I believe if the tag "user" is not present in Firebase shouldn't Firebase create it itself?

Exact error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference()' on a null object reference
    at com.smd.firebasequiz.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
```

Firebase screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Check if the button id is `bottom` that you've set in XML.

Comment: Please share your xml file.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Apprently I used 'bottom' instead of 'button'. Can you help with the NPE on DatabaseReference please?

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;` here `mDatabase` is equal to null, so you need to initialize it before calling any methods in the class `FirebaseDatabase`:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("user");
```

Comment: Good eyes. This is not the answer to his initial error and it addresses another possible error source. It is not sure where he initializes his `mDatabase`. It could be in `onStart()` which would not produce an `NullPointerException` in the `onClickListener()` written in `onCreate()`.

Comment: I doubt he is initializing it anywhere.. but yes it seems op just changed the question completely...

Comment: I added my entire activity code. This prevented the crashing due to NPE but the data isn't getting save to Firebase. My Firebase is still empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the access modifier of the DatabaseReference object. Make it default (by just removing the word *private*).  Also, make an empty default constructor of *StudentInformation* class.

Comment: I updated the code like you said. Kindly look at it. Still on button click event, I'm getting the Toast indicating button is being executed but nothing is uploaded to Firebase